# How to provide multiple images with Lottie on Android

Tags: android, lottie

I'm developing an app with Lottie animations. One of lottie animation needs two image files(img_0.png, img1_.png).

For example,

```
lottie json file [ data.json ] : {"v":"5.1.7","fr":60,"ip":0,"op":120,"w":180,"h":200,"nm":"2","ddd":0,"assets":[{"id":"image_0","w":96,"h":96,"u":"images/","p":"img_0.png"},{"id":"image_1","w":180,"h":180,"u":"images/","p":"img_1.png"}],....
```

I can't prepare all images for LottieAnimationView in main/assets folder, so I'm using "setImageAssetDelegate" method to get multiple images from URLs asynchronously.

This is my code:

```
        Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://www.google.co.kr/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                    LottieAnimationView lottie = findViewById(R.id.lottie);
                    lottie.setImageAssetDelegate(new ImageAssetDelegate() {
                        @Override
                        public Bitmap fetchBitmap(LottieImageAsset asset) {
                            return resource;
                        }
                    });
                    lottie.playAnimation();
                }
            });
```

But if I use "setImageAssetDelegate" method, I can put only one image to Lottie. I want to put multiple different images in one Lottie animation.

[image: not like this]

I don't want this. (the code above shows this animation).

[image: but like this]

I need this with "setImageAssetDelegate" method.

Does anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching the images asynchronously will not work. 
The `ImageAssetDelegate` is meant to be a "provider" of the images that the animation needs when playing.

Its' method `public Bitmap fetchBitmap(LottieImageAsset asset)` will be called for each image in the animation while the animation is playing and it's your responsibility to provide the correct one, where the [LottieImageAsset](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieImageAsset.java) passed to that method will give you the details on which image is needed at that moment taken from the animation `json` file.

You can use `Glide` to fetch these images, need to keep in mind though that you'll have to fetch them synchonously and the animation will not continue playing until that image is loaded / provided by you.

An example:

```
LottieAnimationView lottie = findViewById(R.id.lottie);
lottie.setImageAssetDelegate(new ImageAssetDelegate() {
    @Override
    public Bitmap fetchBitmap(LottieImageAsset asset) {
        return Glide.loadSychronous("http://" + asset.getId + ".png");
    }
});
lottie.playAnimation();
```

Note: this is pseudo-code, you'll have to look up how to load images synchronously with `Glide` and you'll have to come up with a way to match the image id with the correct image url.

Another route would be using `Glide` to load *all* the images needed for the animation, save them (in memory or external storage) and only then start playing the animation; This might work for a small animation; for anything larger you'll run into trouble because a. the loading of all images takes too long or b. you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can load images into lottie dynamically. In this example, I am loading via URL. You can load a bundled image as well similarly.

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    lottie.addLottieOnCompositionLoadedListener {
                        val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, 282, 167, false)
                        lottie.updateBitmap("image_0", scaledBitmap)
                    }
                }
                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                }
            })
```

image_0 is the id of the image you want to replace in lottie json under "assets" object.
You can repeat this process similarly for image_1 as well.

```
"assets": [{
    "id": "image_0",
    "w": 282,
    "h": 167,
    "u": ""}]
```

Scaling the bitmap is optional.